# EAS remote wipe failure

Tags: exchange-2010, group-policy, activesync

I am getting the following error when trying to perform a remote wipe in Exchange 2010 via "Manage Mobile Device" within Recipient Configuration | Mailbox.  I click the help link which leads me to a TechNet document that states the following:

> You've found an error that doesn't have an article written about it. Don't worry though, help is >still available. The forums are the best place to start.
>
> Error: The ActiveSyncDevice
>   l.com/HCRC/Users/Analysts/WS/ExchangeActiveSyncDevices/Android§androidc1717220235 cannot
>   be found. Click here for help...
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms.exch.err.default(EXCHG.140).aspx?v=14.1.355.1&t=exchgf1&e=ms.exch.err.Ex0FBD0C
>
> Exchange Management Shell command attempted: Clear-ActiveSyncDevice
>   -Identity 'l.com/HCRC/Users/Analysts/WS/ExchangeActiveSyncDevices/Android§androidc1717220235'

Comment: Maybe that § character is breaking something.  See what the output looks like when you pull info on the device with `Get-ActiveSyncDevice`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know why EMC was unable to handle this request, I was able to complete the request though the Shell by explicity allowing devices.  I was also able to remove partnerships through OWA.

[Use the Shell to disable a device for Exchange ActiveSync](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232080.aspx)

I am Still accepting answers if any one knows why EMC failed to remove EAS partnerships.  This is a recurring problem.